# Local Module Not Found in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, modulenotfounderror

In Node.js, I created my own custom module called `apiEndpoints.js`. However, when I try to access it, I get a Cannot find module error by Node.js. Below is my `Server.js` code:

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import Cors from "cors";
import apiEndpoints from "./routes/apiEndpoints";

// Initialization
const app = express();
const port = process.env.port || 80;
const connection_url =
  "mongodb+srv://admin:EUl8KIA9dLv7qXKa@cluster0.mblf7.mongodb.net/appDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(Cors());

// DB Config
mongoose.connect(connection_url);

// API Endpoints
app.use(apiEndpoints);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on localhost: ${port}`);
});
```

Below is my `apiEndpoints.js` code:

```
import express from "express";
import Users from "../models/users";

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/users", (req, res) => {
  Users.find((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(data);
    }
  });
});

router.get("/user/:username", (req, res) => {
  const username = req.params.username;

  Users.findOne({ username: username }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(data);
    }
  });
});

router.post("/user/create", (req, res) => {
  const user = req.body;

  Users.create(user, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      res.status(201).send(data);
    }
  });
});

router.put("/user/:username", (req, res) => {
  const username = req.params.username;
  const updatedData = req.body;

  Users.findOneAndUpdate(
    { username: username },
    updatedData,
    { new: true },
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
      } else {
        res.status(200).send(data);
      }
    }
  );
});

router.delete("/user/delete/:username", (req, res) => {
  const username = req.params.username;

  Users.findOneAndDelete({ username: username }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(data);
    }
  });
});

export default router;
```

And, this is my folder structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

Also, below, is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.4"
  }
}
```

So my question is why is it saying "Module not Found" when `Server.js` tries to access `apiEndpoints.js`?

Comment: Could you post your `package.json` as well to verify the type key is being used correctly? I also wonder if your `package.json` being a sibling to `server.js` is the cause. Node [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_determining_module_system) states: "Node.js will treat the following as ES modules when passed to `node` as the initial input, or when referenced by `import` statements within ES module code: [...] Files ending in `.js` when the nearest **parent** `package.json` file contains a top-level `"type"` field with a value of `"module"`". (Emphasis on "parent" mine)

Comment: @Wing Okay, I edited my question to include the package.json.

Comment: Thanks, your usage of the type field looks correct  Onto the other possibility: your `package.json` cannot be a sibling of `server.js` and needs to be in a parent directory. Does either moving `server.js` and `routes` into a directory that is a sibling to the `package.json` or moving the `package.json` into the parent directory resolve this?

Comment: What do you mean moving the `package.json` into the parent directory? The `package.json` is already in the parent directory. The `apiEndpoints.js` file is the only file that is located under the `routes` folder.

Comment: `server.js` and `package.json` are currently siblings, right? Could you try putting `package.json` in a directory that is a parent of `server.js`? There are two ways to do this: move `server.js` down a directory (you may want to move `routes` down a directory too so paths aren't broken) or move `package.json` up a directory.

Comment: Do you mean like this: https://imgur.com/a/u56hthS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so after hours of hard-work, I was able to solve my problem. So what my problem was that I didn't setup the es6 for Node.js properly. So, I followed along [this](https://medium.com/@abs4real16.ma/writing-es6-in-nodejs-using-babel-10731b8032fc) tutorial on Medium, and was able to setup of es6 properly by using Babel. Then, I added the `.js` file extension on all of my imports, and it works.

Comment: Oh in fact, that's the reason – it's not the Babel setup, you need the extension. If you remove your Babel setup and keep the extension does it still work? If it does, I'll post an answer with more detail.

Comment: So if I remove Babel, then it doesn't work. Previously, I didn't have Babel installed, so looks like that's the problem!

Comment: That's really strange. I've tested this with a minimal Node project – just a `package.json` with `{ "type": "module" }`, an `index.js` that imports something from `module.js`, (no Babel) – using Node lts/12-latest and it works if I use an extension. If I remove the extension I can reproduce your issue. This is expected behaviour and should be present from Node 12.something (I can't remember the exact version ES modules are supported). So it's strange you need Babel to get things working. Which version of Node are you using?

Comment: What do you mean as an extension? Which extension are you using?

Comment: Extension as in file extension. If my import paths have the file extension things work, if I remove the file extension from the import path I can reproduce your error.

Comment: Yeah, before I installed Babel, I also tried including the .js file extension, and it still didn't work. The current Node.js version I'm using is v16.7.0

Comment: Whaaat!? Welp, glad Babel has resolved it for you. I don't understand why it's not working for you without Babel. And I don't think I'm going to spend more effort thinking about this, hah

Comment: Haha, yeah I don't know why. Thanks for going through this with me!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the file extension to all import and export statements then it will work without Babel

Comment: I already tried that, but this question has already been solved for me anyways.

By the way, I noticed that installing Babel is only accurate for this specific project because in any other node project importing and exporting with the file extension works anyways.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you need to remove this line from package.json

```
  "type": "module", // remove this
```

if you added it without knowing why, at least that is what happened to me

Comment: That does nothing, I purposely added that so the `import` statement would work. There's no point in adding answers to questions which are already solved and when I tired all of the conventional solutions.